# SQL order by this format (0:0:0.8) H:M:S.MS - ORDER BY/ASC not working

Tags: php, sql, timer

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT `runner`,`finished` 
    FROM `runs` 
    WHERE `gamename`='$_SESSION[game]' 
    ORDER BY finished ASC
");
```

finished is the time H:M:S.MS

it doesn't sort at all.

Here is the data:

```
0:0:5.1 
0:0:5.2 
0:0:5.4 
0:0:5.7  
0:0:7.0  
0:0:8.9 
0:0:9.3 
0:0:9.8 
0:10:25.2    
0:13:15.2    
0:1:27.1     
0:1:50.4 
0:2:27.9 
0:5:30.9
```

Comment: Please show sample data and the type of the `finished` column.

Comment: It most likely does order, but not the way you expect it to. This might be due to the fact that you're doing a string-sort, or due to formatting, etc. We won't be able to help you until you show the data-type of the finished column at the least.

Comment: perhaps i can assign a Place (this is a game racing site) like 1st 2nd Third and sort by place.

Comment: i'd use an integer for 'finished' and create a function to convert it to your desired format after you get it from the db.  Then you will have no trouble sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Your ordering is probably going screwy because "finished" is a text field. Try converting it to a date field in your order by clause:

```
...
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(finished, '%h:%i:%s.%f')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it even if it's a little complex :

```
SELECT * FROM runs
ORDER BY
substring_index(finished, ':', 1),
substring_index(substring_index(finished, ':', 2), ':', -1),
substring_index(substring_index(finished, ':', -1), '.', 1),
substring_index(substring_index(finished, ':', -1), '.', -1)
```

[Test here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69acf6/22)